# Relate more than one column with lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the query below that relates only the ProcessId. I need to know how to relate the lists processes and pendingProcess by ProcessId and GroupId. Thankful.

```
        return process.Join(
            pendingProcess,
            p => p.ProcessId,
            pp => pp.ProcessId,
            (p, pp) => new Process
            {
                ProcessId = p.ProcessId,
                GroupId = p.GroupId,
                Text = p.Text,
            }

        ).ToList();
```

Comment: Is `ProcessId`  and `GroupId` present in both list?

Comment: Yes, Columns are in both lists. Thankful.

Comment: @er-sho Thank you very much for your reply. I am intending to follow as it is in the code. Code consults use lambda.

Comment: You can try like this => `p => new { ProcessId = Convert.ToInt32(p.ProcessId), GroupId  = Convert.ToInt32(p.GroupId) }` and same for second line also to *Slava* answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use composite join condition via anonymous types:

```
return process.Join(pendingProcess,
    p => new { p.ProcessId, p.GroupId }
    pp => new { ProcessId = (int)pp.ProcessId, pp.GroupId }
    (p, pp) => new Process
    {
        ProcessId = p.ProcessId,
        GroupId = p.GroupId,
        Text = p.Text,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect, I have another problem. The data types of p.ProcessId is int and pp.ProcessId is decimal.

Comment: You can try to cast one of these fields. Look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer lambda expression;

```
return process
    .Where(p => pendingProcess.Any(pp=> pp.GroupId == p.GroupId && pp.Precessid == p.PreocessId))
    .Select(p=> new Process
            {
                ProcessId = p.ProcessId,
                GroupId = p.GroupId,
                Text = p.Text,
            }).ToList();
```